# payload not coming for post api in swagger documentation: spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, post, swagger, swagger-2.0

I have a post API with @RequestBody (Map<String, Object> payload). While processing this post request I am converting this payload to respective model object(ex: User) using object mapper.
When I document this API I am seeing {} in payload section in swagger. Instead of {} I want to show the Model object.

Which annotation I should use here? Please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to use actual model type i.e User instead of Object with @RequestBody itself, for swagger to auto generate request payload.

Comment: Hi @NakulGoyal Thanks. But I am not suppose to change the business code. Is there any other way to ask swagger to display User object instead of {}

Comment: Swagger will read it as Object, which can have any field. [So it will show {} only]
You have to change business code for swagger to show exact fields.